# Fastest way to determine if a 3D point is within an axis aligned cube?

Tags: c++, performance, 3d, geometry

Assume you are given a single 3D point to be tested and another two 3D points representing the maximum and minimum of a cube.

The obvious solution using, at worst, 6 conditional statements is as follows:

```
if (point.x < cubemin.x || point.y < cubemin.y || point.z < cubemin.z
 || point.x > cubemax.x || point.y > cubemax.y || point.z > cubemax.z)
    return false; //is not within cube
return true; //is within cube
```

Conditional statements are some of the most computationally expensive instructions to execute. Is there **any** way to reduce the number of checks required? Performance in this case is crucial above all else.

Comment: The "computationally expensive" part is the fact that there's a branch at all, not that it has 6 tests in it. And I don't see how you can reduce the number of tests.

Comment: @ooga are you saying that each test is not the equivalent of a new branch or otherwise does not require additional branch prediction?

Comment: You don't tell the data type, this is essential information ! Are your points more often inside or outside ? Have you tried using a bitwise or | instead of logical or || ?

Comment: You can trade some comparisons for addition or subtraction, but don't think that's any better. An approximation might save some time depending on the data type.

Comment: Are you doing this on a single point, or many points?  Because while there is no real optimization for a single point, there are other approaches one can use if there are many points.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, there is no other way to work around maximum of 6 comparisons.

However, in the aspect of computer architecture, it is possible to do it all in parallel.
A vector computer can do lots of similar things (such as your comparisons of max and min, etc.) in parallel.

So, that depends on what platform your program will be implemented on, and if that platform provide some vector instructions.

Or extremely, if your work is so critical, you may try to fabricate your own ASIC CPU chip.

Answer (score 2):

There is this trick to reduce the number of tests (I am not advising using it...):

Assuming all coordinates are unsigned integers, then `xmin <= x && x <= xmax` can be reduced to `x - xmin <= xmax - xmin`.

1. If `xmin <= x && x <= xmax`, this returns `true` as expected.
2. If `xmax < x`, then `x - xmin > xmax - xmin`, so this returns `false` as expected.
3. If `x < xmin`, then `x - xmin` wraps around (giving `MAX_UINT + 1 + x - xmin`), and `xmax - xmin < MAX_UINT + 1 + x - xmin`, so this returns `false` as expected.

Comment: This, in fact, trades comparisons for subtractions.  The cost of computations is almost the same.  (two comparisons + one logical-OR vs. two subtractions + one comparison)